# How to use Alembic outside of python applications?

Tags: python, alembic

I am looking to extend on top of or use an existing tool for the purpose of database migrations.
As we have applications in different languages, I need the tool to be language independent. I came across [dbmate](https://github.com/amacneil/dbmate) which solves my use case but Go language and its lack of support for MSSQL had me have it as a last option.

I see that [Alembic](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic) is widely popular too. Any insights as to how this tool works with non-python applications? If I were to extend it to be language-independent how much effort would that require?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: When using alembic you write your database migration scripts in python, though the application that uses this database can be written in any other language.

Comment: I just want to use raw SQL for writing my migration scripts. I do not want people to learn python just to use this tool.

Comment: Alembic only makes sense for a project already using sqlalchemy.

Comment: @jordanm May I know why. If I were to use alembic for my new applications and new databases to start supporting database migrations why is it not a good idea? I am not looking to support legacy applications to move towards this path right now.

Comment: Alembic supports raw sql queries along with pythonic ORM-based. @jordanm you're not right. Alembic benifits from projects that are in python and using SQLAlchemy but it is not mandatory